# Why don't the RPC subscription methods work when we use finalized commitment?

Tags: candy-machine-v2, metaplex-js

I'm trying to make a program that monitors candy machine v2 then getting nft informations using metaplex.
Why is my program not returning anything when I specify "finalized" commitment?

````
import { Metaplex, keypairIdentity, bundlrStorage } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl, Keypair, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
import WebSocket from "ws";
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));
var socket
var websocketurl


const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));


const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection)
    .use(keypairIdentity("cndy3Z4yapfJBmL3ShUp5exZKqR3z33thTzeNMm2gRZ"))
    .use(bundlrStorage());

async function np(){
}

async function openConnection() {
    try{
            websocketurl = 'wss://tame-solemn-layer.solana-mainnet.discover.quiknode.pro/6f2546981f01160bfe3685e910532b69c7409047/'
            socket = new WebSocket(websocketurl);
            socket.onopen = function() {
                init()
            };
            socket.onclose = function() {
                console.log("hello")
            };

            socket.onmessage = function(message) {
                try{
                    //data = JSON.parse(message.data);
                    fetch("https://public-api.solscan.io/transaction/"+JSON.parse(message.data).params.result.value.signature)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(response => response.parsedInstruction[1].params.mint)
                    .then(response => {if (typeof response !== 'undefined'){
                        const Mintadress = new PublicKey(response) ; 
                        const nft = metaplex.nfts().findByMint({Mintadress}).run();
                        console.log(nft.json)
                    }})
                    
                  
  
                    .catch(error => np());
              }catch(error){
                console.log(error)
              }

            };
            socket.onerror = function(error) {
                console.log(error)
            };
        
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}

async function init() {
    if (socket) {
        var message = JSON.stringify({
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "id": 1,
            "method": "logsSubscribe",
            "params": [
                {
                "mentions": [ "cndy3Z4yapfJBmL3ShUp5exZKqR3z33thTzeNMm2gRZ" ]
                },
                {
                "commitment": "finalized"
                }
            ]
        })
        socket.send(message);
        console.log("start listening")
    }
}

async function closeConnection() {
    if (socket) {
        console.log("close")
        socket.close()      
    }
}

async function _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes;
}

openConnection()```
````

Comment: I have observed the same behavior on program accounts subscription. It works with processed/confirmed commitments, but not with finalized commitment.

Comment: sorry i'm new to solana what's the difference with precced and finalized commitement

Comment: Do you observe any errors or close events when you observe the code producing no results? I created a reduced test case here and received messages just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/d4Ljhsp2/

Comment: How many subscriptions are you making against the RPC? I've seen cases where RPC providers limit the number of open subscriptions you may have, and start dropping them or closing connections with too many open subscriptions.

Comment: i had one subscription a just switched i used solscan api